# C# Garbage Collector's "KeepAlive" and Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have an application which is some sort of test for someone and lasts about 30 minutes. During the start of the program (3rd party), my code is called and I register the time and return some info to the application, and I save the test as "ONGOING".

After about 30 minutes, I expect the program to return to me and send me the results of the test so I can save and finish the process. Sometimes this doesn't happen for various reasons.
So I'm thinking in implementing a code to start a thread, sleep it for about 35 minutes (the maximum duration it can), and when it runs it does one thing only: if the test is still as "ONGOING", it updates it to "FAILED" or some other status.

However, I've read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011831/new-thread-and-garbage-collection) that C#'s garbage collector **can** collect threads that it assumes as inactive, and I'm worried about this, so I'd like to ask how does this [KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx) method works with threads, or if there's any reliable way to test it (because even if I did wait all 35 min for it to happen, there might be a situation where the GC actually collects the thread and everything fails).

So, what's the correct way for this to work, or if it isn't like this, how should I do it?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //After all the startup functions are done...
    Thread thread = new Thread( () => UpdateTest(1) );
    thread.Start();

    //My thread is supposedly safe...?
    GC.KeepAlive(thread);
}

static void UpdateTest(int testID)
{
    Thread.Sleep(210000); //Sleep for 35min

    //Search the database for the testID, update it if it's still ONGOING.
}
```

Comment: Would making a service for the long running process handle this for you?

Comment: If you're talking about jitbit's answer, I suspect there's more to that than meets the eye. It's not GC... Basically this question is a duplicate of the one you've already linked to, isn't it?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think it's a duplicate, because my thread won't be running at all, it'll be sleeping for a long time before it starts, so basically it's a question about jitbit's answer. That's why I looked for solutions and found about the KeepAlive method.

Comment: @Danicco: So you should have added a comment on jitbit's answer. And if the thread is sleeping, it's still fundamentally active. I have strong doubts about that jitbit's answer...

Comment: `KeepAlive` isn't going to do much there, since it only keeps an object alive while inside the current method. `Start` is non-blocking, so the main thread will exit almost immediately. The program is then kept running by the spawned thread.

Comment: @Danicco Is that fair now? That answer is deleted. It is indeed a wrong answer. You won't be able to see that poor answer anymore(till you get 10k reputation I guess).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks, I also didn't assume it to be entirely true, but reading from here (and seeing it had 3 upvotes) made me think that it **could** be true... and it never hurts to play safe imo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Threads are not aborted due to GC. In fact, it is not possible to reliably abort a thread. (Try to abort `try {} finally { while(true); }`.)

The answer you reference is wrong. But there are 3 correct answers in that question. You just happened to believe the wrong, minority answer.

There is no problem for you to solve.

Comment: And I doubt that answer will be around much longer.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling it is the responsibility of high-experience SO users to downvote such answers. So far, the responsibility has not been picked up on.

Comment: Please vote for deleting that answer. It misleads beginners, if they don't ask a question as OP did, it will stay as misconception itself.