# .NET Threads and Garbage Collection/Phantom process

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, windows-services, nservicebus

I'm currently trying to work out how best to run a .NET Core 2.x application as a Windows Service, specifically to run an NServiceBus endpoint for a messaging system. My original prototype was built from some of the [Windows Service hosting docs](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/windows-service) from Particular. I then took that functioning prototype and turned it into a .NET Standard library for other team members to build from, but found that it wasn't super intuitive for them (or myself if I looked away from it for 2 weeks).

Naturally, after I built a functioning prototype and it was deployed to production, I found a more elegant solution that uses .NET Core's `GenericHostBuilder`, courtesy of a [Mr. Steve Gordon](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/running-net-core-generic-host-applications-as-a-windows-service). The majority of the code makes sense to me, but I'm hung up on the `new Thread(...).Start();`, likely because I don't have any specific experience with using `Thread` in C# and .NET.

1. `new`ing up a `Thread` and maintaining no reference to it feels really wrong. I'm concerned that doing that might lead to a memory leak or the Garbage Collector will pick it up? I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011853/5884242) SO answer which gives me some reassurance that even if I don't hold a reference to the `Thread`, the CLR will. So it sounds like there shouldn't be any concern of the GC finalizing the thread, right?
2. Could anyone explain to me why `Abort()` is not called for the `Thread`? Is it because the CLR manages threads and knows to stop other threads when the main thread shuts down? Or is does it have something to do with calling the `ServiceBase.Stop()` method in the `IHostLifetime.StopAsync()` method?

If these things can be explained in some documentation of `Thread` somewhere, I'm more than happy to get an "RTFM" and find the docs. I just haven't found anything that's given me a clear explanation at this point.

Comment: Writing a multithreaded C# program correctly is extremely difficult and you do not understand even the very basics. **Find an expert to help you**.  You will get it wrong, and worse, it will be wrong in subtle ways that do not show up in testing, but do in production.

Comment: I promise you I know the basics of multithreaded programming and understand that multithreaded programs can result in difficult to detect bugs (I've written a few multithread things and seen this myself). However you're correct that I have not yet used C# for multithreading.

Comment: And better yet, instead of telling me to "Find an expert" maybe point me to some docs or material to read so that I can learn and grow myself? Perhaps I don't have "an expert" with C# multithreading available?

Comment: Asking for off-site tutorials is **explicitly off topic for this web site**. That said, the threading chapters in *C# in a Nutshell* are very good. I was the editor of a recent edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a threads execution has finished and falls out of scope the, garbage collector will eventually reclaim the resources (when if feels the need). `Thread` also doesn't implement `IDisposable` so you really don't need to bother yourself with it hanging around (unless you are executing endless loops within it)

In regards to `Thread.Abort` vs `Thread.Interrupt`, My honest answer is that you should never use either of these methods to terminate a thread. It is advisable not to use `Thread.Abort` or `Thread.Interrupt` methods at all - you should rather take advantage of synchronization objects (like, WaitHandles or Semaphores, etc, etc, etc) and perform a graceful termination of the threads you are using.

In the wise [words of Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560567/1612975) (the resident CLR wizard)

> In short, `Thread.Abort` is at best indicative of bad design, possibly
> unreliable, and extremely dangerous. It should be avoided at all
> costs; the only time you should ever even consider aborting a thread
> is in some sort of "emergency shutdown" code where you are attempting
> to tear down an appdomain as cleanly as possible.

**Some additional reading**

- [Do we need to dispose or terminate a thread in C# after usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698107/do-we-need-to-dispose-or-terminate-a-thread-in-c-sharp-after-usage)
- [C# Thread object lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3699147/5884242)

Comment: So, effectively, a thread should reach a natural stopping point on it's own, and any synchronization should use common strategies like the ones you mentioned. And basically the `ServiceBase.Run(this)` will handle the necessary start/stop code that will cause the `Thread` to finish safely, right?

Comment: @willwolfram18 that's a fair enough interpretation

Comment: Thought I'd throw in this as some additional reading as well (a link within your suggested post): https://stackoverflow.com/q/3699147/5884242